# Why are the contents of my pages getting mixed up when reading PDF?

Tags: c#, .net, itext7, text-extraction

I am using iText7 to read the text from a pdf file. This works fine for the first page. After that the contents of the pages are somehow getting mixed up. So at page 3 of the document I have lines that contain content of page 1 and 3. The text of page 2 shows the exact same lines as page 1 (but in "reallity" they are completely different).

- Page 1, real: ~36 lines, result 36 lines -> GREAT
- Page 2, real: >50 lines, result 36 lines (==Page 1)
- Page 3, real: ~16 lines, result 47 lines (adds and mixes with lines of page 1)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/63gy5cg1othy6ci/Dividenden_Microsoft.pdf?dl=0

For reading the document I use the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StockMarket
{
    class PdfReader
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Reads PDF file by a given path.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">The path to the file</param>
        /// <param name="pageCount">The number of pages to read (0=all, 1 by default) </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DocumentTree PdfToText(string path, int pageCount=1 )
        {
            var pages = new DocumentTree();
            using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader reader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(path))
            {
                using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(reader))
                {
                    var strategy = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();

                    // set up pages to read
                    int pagesToRead = 1;
                    if (pageCount > 0)
                    {
                        pagesToRead = pageCount;
                    }
                    if (pagesToRead > pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages() || pageCount==0)
                    {
                        pagesToRead = pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages();
                    }

                    // for each page to read...
                    for (int i = 1; i <= pagesToRead; ++i)
                    {
                        // get the page and save it
                        var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
                        var txt = iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
                        pages.Add(txt);
                    }
                    pdfDocument.Close();
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            return pages;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A class representing parts of a PDF document.
    /// </summary>
    class DocumentTree
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public DocumentTree()
        {
            Pages = new List<DocumentPage>();
        }

        private List<DocumentPage> _pages;
        /// <summary>
        /// The pages of the document
        /// </summary>
        public List<DocumentPage> Pages
        {
            get { return _pages; }
            set { _pages = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a <see cref="DocumentPage"/> to the document.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="page">The text of the <see cref="DocumentPage"/>.</param>
        public void Add(string page)
        {
            Pages.Add(new DocumentPage(page));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A class representing a single page of a document
    /// </summary>
    class DocumentPage
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="pageContent">The pages content as text</param>
        public DocumentPage(string pageContent)
        {
            // set the content to the input
            CompletePage = pageContent;

            // split the content by lines
            var splitter = new string[] { "\n" };
            foreach (var line in CompletePage.Split(splitter, StringSplitOptions.None))
            {
                // add lines to the page if the content is not empty
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                {                    
                    _lines.Add(new Line(line));
                }
            }

        }

        private List<Line> _lines = new List<Line>();
        /// <summary>
        /// The lines of text of the <see cref="DocumentPage"/>
        /// </summary>
        public List<Line> Lines
        {
            get
            {
                return _lines;
            }            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The text of the complete <see cref="DocumentPage"/>.
        /// </summary>
        private string CompletePage;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A class representing a single line of text
    /// </summary>
    class Line
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public Line(string lineContent)
        {
            CompleteLine = lineContent;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The words of the <see cref="Line"/>.
        /// </summary>
        public List<string> Words
        {
            get
            {
                return CompleteLine.Split(" ".ToArray()).Where((word)=> { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word); }).ToList();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The complete text of the <see cref="Line"/>.
        /// </summary>
        private string CompleteLine;

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return CompleteLine;
        }
    }
}
```

The page tree is a simple tree with the pages, consisting of lines (read page split by "\n") and lines consisting of words (line split by " ") but the **txt** in the loop already contains the messed up content (so my tree is not causing the issues).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: PDF documents are not "structured" the way that HTML and XML documents are - PDFs are literally just a bunch of drawing instructions that can appear in any order to produce the final rendered page output. You can only read PDF files "correctly" if they're Tagged PDFs - however many PDF generators don't tag PDFs, thus making them almost impossible to be machine-readable.

Comment: Can you share the PDF in question?

Comment: mkl : done, @Dai : OK, but I think that would only explain mistakes in the text of one page, not when text is shown that is not at the page at all , wouldn't it?

Comment: Beware of using itext; their libraries contain a time bomb. The product is ostensibly dual licensed commercially and AGPL, but the authors misinterpret the AGPL as requiring your project to also be OSS. If you use itext in a private project without a commercial or OSS license key, itext will start blasting out nagging log spam after a few months... just enough time for you to get into production and think everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some parsing event listeners, in particular most text extraction strategies, are not meant to be reused on multiple pages. Instead you should create a new instance for each page.

As a rule of thumb each such listener that collects information while a page is parsed, and afterwards allows you to access that data (like text extraction strategies allow you to access the collected page text), most likely must be instantiated separately for each page if you don't want the data from all pages to accumulate.

Thus, in your code move the strategy instantiation

```
var strategy = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
```

into the `for` loop:

```
// for each page to read...
for (int i = 1; i <= pagesToRead; ++i)
{
    var strategy = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Listener.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
    // get the page and save it
    var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
    var txt = iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
    pages.Add(txt);
}
```

Alternatively you can shorten the loop to

```
// for each page to read...
for (int i = 1; i <= pagesToRead; ++i)
{
    // get the page and save it
    var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
    var txt = iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page);
    pages.Add(txt);
}
```

This `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage` overload creates a new `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` instance each time internally.